# US tax 2021 for H1b and H4 visa holders- when to use 6013 h Election

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, h-1b-visa

I was on H1B and spouse on H4, have been filing US tax for 2015-2020 as married filing jointly and have been in US 365 days for all 5 years.

In 2021 - we stayed from Jan to April 2021 which is less than 183 days in US and have income only for that period in US. My question is "should we use 6013 h Election" form ? My CA is suggesting it however i am not convinced after reading about 6013h form. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you terminated your residency? What's your current status?

Comment: I am an indian citizen and currently in india

Comment: What is the goal of this election? It sounds like you might be referring to either the closer connection exception to the Substantial Presence Test (form 8840; 26 USC 7701(b)(3)(B)) to make you nonresident alien for the whole year, or earlier residency termination date for last year of residency (26 USC 7701(b)(2)(B)) to make you dual-status. Though you can't file jointly in either of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why the CA would suggest the 6013(h) election. The election is for non-resident spouse to be considered resident to allow MFJ filing, but in your case you both are residents (based on the [substantial presence](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test) test) and no election is needed.

I suggest asking the CA about what exactly they're proposing. You do not need the 6013(h) election based on the facts you've presented.